# Windows Server 2012 - two NICs, wrong one selected

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I have a server with two NICs, as follows.

- One has IP address 192.168.0.47/24. This network has no router / gateway / etc.
- One has IP address 172.16.92.45, and is bridged to a tap adapter for OpenVPN.

I'm trying to communicate with a device at 192.168.0.204, and failing. Wireshark confirms that attempts to ping 192.168.0.204 go via the interface 172.16.92.45, not 192.168.0.47, which surprises me. tracert confirms that the pings go to the default gateway, 172.16.92.12, never to be seen again.

ipconfig says:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Ethernet adapter Embedded LOM 1 Port 2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b40f:8c41:a781:a89b%12
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.47
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Ethernet adapter Network Bridge:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4d2:2673:7ff4:8676%18
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.92.45
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.92.12

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B63DCFB1-4179-45E6-9268-299D4526831A}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{78520E8A-472A-4BBD-9440-7BF50D172859}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

The routing table is:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 19...00 ff 4d 58 89 8e ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #2
 12...98 f2 b3 8f bb e5 ......HPE Ethernet 1Gb 2-port 332i Adapter #2
 18...00 ff f8 2b 19 b1 ......Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.16.92.12     172.16.92.45    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       172.16.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      172.16.92.45    266
     172.16.92.45  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.92.45    266
   172.16.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.92.45    266
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.47    276
     192.168.0.47  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.47    276
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.47    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.16.92.45    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.47    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.92.45    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.47    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.16.92.12  Default 
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.16.92.12  Default 
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 18    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 18    266 fe80::4d2:2673:7ff4:8676/128
                                    On-link
 12    276 fe80::b40f:8c41:a781:a89b/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

I would've thought the route to 192.168.0.0 / 255.255.255.0 having interface 192.168.0.47 would've meant 192.168.0.47 got used to ping 192.168.0.204, but apparently not.

If it makes any difference, the two NICs actually connect to the same physical LAN (different switches, but connected). I'm using the two IP address ranges because I'm working remotely, and trying to communicate with a device on the LAN that has its factory default IP (192.168.0.200). The plan was to change the IP address of the secondary port to 192.168.0.47 (done), access and configure the device at 192.168.0.200 (failing), including change its IP address to something in the 172.16.0.0 network. The approach has worked a treat with other devices in the past on this same LAN. But not today.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it. The remote IP address factory defaults didn't match the documentation, for once. Similar models had worked so well already, I didn't think to look there. Rookie mistake.

To get a better idea what was going on:

```
[gateway]<--172.16.0.0/16--[server]--192.168.0.0/24-->[factory default device]
```

I had used `tracert` to confirm that pings to 192.168.0.204 were going to the gateway on the 172.16.0.0/16 network, which made no sense to me. I then used Wireshark and filtered for ICMP, and it confirmed that no ICMP was going out the 192.168.0.0/24 interface. Very weird, I thought.

Where I went wrong: I should have also checked for ARP, not just ICMP.

The server's default gateway is on the 172.16.0.0/16 LAN. There is no gateway on the 192.168.0.0./24 LAN.

When I tried to ping 192.168.0.204, the server sent an ARP request first on the 192.168.0.0/24 interface, trying to find the Ethernet address associated with the IP address, as you'd expect. When there was no ARP reply (because the device's factory default had changed), the server sent the ICMP request to the default gateway (which I saw when I filtered Wireshark for ICMP).

Thanks all for your time and thoughts! Muchly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain the problem and the exact solution, for the benefit of future readers. As it stands now, this post has no value for us. And what's the point of the sarcasm in the last sentence?

Comment: Good point. Edited. There was no sarcasm on the last line, but there was an answer that got deleted (not by me), and I did appreciate the thought and care that went into it.

Comment: Yes, that answer could be useful, so I proposed it for undeletion.